# Call to functions that prints, avoid new line

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have function that prints an array:

```
In [93]:

printArr(arrs[0], Nrows, Ncols)
# # #  
# # #  
# # #  
O O O  
O O O  
O O O
```

Where in the *printArr* function I add a comma (,) to the end of that function's call to pythons *print* function to get the output in 3 columns.

BUT, what if I want to make several calls to *printArr*, and have the output stacked to the columns, like this?

```
# # #    O O O 
# # #    # # #
# # #    # # #
O O O    O O O
O O O    O O O
O O O    O O O
```

Two calls to *printArr* just gives me this

```
In [96]:

printArr(arrs[0], Nrows, Ncols)
print " "
printArr(arrs[1], Nrows, Ncols)    
​
# # #  
# # #  
# # #  
O O O  
O O O  
O O O  

O O O  
# # #  
# # #  
# # #  
O O O  
O O O
```

Is there a way to accomplish this, or do I have to redo my entire *printArr* function?

Thanks

EDIT:
Okay, here is my *printArr* function

```
def printArr(arr, Nrows, Ncols):
    for row in range(0, Nrows):
        for col in range(0, Ncols):
            if arr[row][col] == 1:
                print '#',
            else:
                print 'O',
        print " "
```

It takes an 3-dimensional Ndarray as input, and I intened to use that function to print all the matrices in that array in a nice way (for example with 3 total columns and 3 total rows)

Thanks again

Comment: You have to redo your function. Once the cursor moves down to a new line, there's no built-in way to go back up and print more stuff. (I'm posting this as a comment and not an answer because "ok, _how_ should I redo my function?" is a can of worms I don't want to open)

Comment: Show us the implementation of your function so that we can help you edit it for the intended output.

Comment: It is a Numpy Ndarray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a row generator and use it in your print functions:

```
def rows(arr):
    for row in arr:
        yield " ".join('#' if c == 1 else 'O' for c in row)

def printArr(arr):
    print "\n".join(rows(arr))

from itertools import izip_longest
def print2Arr(arr1, cols1, arr2, cols2):
    for row1, row2 in izip_longest(rows(arr1), rows(arr2)):
        row1 = row1 or " " * (2 * cols1 - 1)
        row2 = row2 or " " * (2 * cols2 - 1)
        print row1 + "    " + row2
```

Examples:

```
>>> arr1 = [[1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0]]
>>> arr2 = [[1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
>>> printArr(arr1)
# O O
# # O
>>> print2Arr(arr1, 3, arr2, 3)
# O O    # O O
# # O    # # O
         # O O
>>> print2Arr(arr2, 3, arr1, 3)
# O O    # O O
# # O    # # O
# O O
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def printArrays(listOfArrays,cols):
    splittedArrays = [[array[x:x+cols] for x in range(0,len(array),cols)] for array in listOfArrays]
    c = list(zip(*splittedArrays))
    c = ["".join([[" "+"".join(y)][0]for y in x]) for x in c]
    print("\n".join([" ".join(array) for array in c]))

a =["a","b","c","a","b","c"]
b= ["x","y","z","x","y","z"]
printArrays([a,b],3)
printArrays([a,b],2)
```

Comment: Output will be wrong if elements are strings - they get `split`ted.`c=['one','another','string']; printArrays(c,3)` yields `  o n e   a n o   s t r`.